# How to clip to nearest value from a list in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array of values for example

```
[-11, -2, -0.7, -0.2, 0, 0.1, 0.5, 0.9, 2, 7]
```

And I want to clip it to either 0 or 1, whichever is closer. Alternatively to -1 or 1 (unless implementation is any different).

I tried

```
>>> np.asarray(arr).clip(min=-1, max=1)
array([ 0.1, -1. ,  1. ,  0.5])
>>> np.asarray(arr).clip(-1, 1)
array([ 0.1, -1. ,  1. ,  0.5])
>>> np.asarray(arr).clip(-1, 1)
>>> np.asarray(arr).clip(0, 1)
array([0.1, 0. , 1. , 0.5])
```

So it does not work because I expect:
`[-1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]` in case of `clip(-1, 1)`

and 
`[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]` in case of `clip(0, 1)`

How do I do it in the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**General solution using NumPy's [`where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)**

*For -1 to 1*

```
arr = np.array([-11, -2, -0.7, -0.2, 0, 0.1, 0.5, 0.9, 2, 7])

clip_left = -1
clip_right = 1

mean = (clip_left + clip_right)/2

arr = np.where(arr<mean, clip_left, clip_right)
print (arr)
# [-1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1  1  1]
```

---

*For 0 to 1*

```
arr = np.array([-11, -2, -0.7, -0.2, 0, 0.1, 0.5, 0.9, 2, 7])

clip_left = 0
clip_right = 1

mean = (clip_left + clip_right)/2

arr = np.where(arr<mean, clip_left, clip_right)
print (arr)
# [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1]
```

**As a function**

```
arr = np.array([-11, -2, -0.7, -0.2, 0, 0.1, 0.5, 0.9, 2, 7])

def clip(arr, clip_left, clip_right):
    mean = (clip_left + clip_right)/2
    arr = np.where(arr<mean, clip_left, clip_right)
    return arr

print (clip(arr, -1, 1))
# [-1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1  1  1]
```